# Issue with testing a PUT parameter value with Slim

Tags: php, phpunit, slim

I don't exactly understand how it goes with PUT variables and Slim.

Please consider the following route:

```
$app->put('/users/me',function() use ($app){
    $app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $userData = $app->request()->put();
    var_dump($userData);
});
```

This route basically accepts a PUT request and returns whatever variables came with it. When I test it with curl it seems to be working as expected:

```
oris@oris:~/slim-api$ curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X PUT -d "hello=there" http://slim-api.com/users/me
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Thu, 06 Feb 2014 09:53:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.5
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2r6ta2fg6vdk7; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache

array(1) {
    ["hello"]=>
    string(5) "there"
}
```

I wrote a little PHPUnit test for this route with this [bootstrap.php file](https://github.com/there4/slim-unit-testing-example/blob/master/tests/bootstrap.php):

```
 public function testPutUsersMe()
{
    $this->put('/users/me',array("myKey=myValue"));
    $userResponse = $this->response->body();
    var_dump($userResponse);
}
```

I have also added a tiny addition to this bootstrap file to update the superglobals on each request:

```
//sets php super globals so other packages would have access to them on tests context
public function setRequestGlobals($method,$path,$options = array())
{
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = $method;
    if (!empty($options)){
        if ($method === "GET"){
            foreach($options as $key => $value){
                $_GET[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        if ($method === "POST"){
            foreach($options as $key => $value){
                $_POST[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        if ($method === "PUT"){
            foreach($options as $key => $value){
                $_POST[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I call `$this->setRequestGlobals($method,$path,$options);` inside the `request` method.
But this causes the following response which isn't quite right:

```
oris@oris:~/slim-api$ phpunit
PHPUnit 3.7.29 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/oris/slim-api/phpunit.xml

...........string(44) "Array
(
    [slim.input] => myKey=myValue
)
"


Time: 119 ms, Memory: 7.75Mb

OK (11 tests, 85 assertions)
oris@oris:~/slim-api$
```

What I mean by "isn't quite right" is that the `[slim.input]` is now the parameter value, and the key and the value are the value. If I change the route (and the test) method to `POST`, I get the expected desired output:

```
oris@oris:~/slim-api$ phpunit
PHPUnit 3.7.29 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/oris/slim-api/phpunit.xml

...........string(33) "Array
(
    [myKey] => myValue
)
"


Time: 128 ms, Memory: 7.75Mb

OK (11 tests, 85 assertions)
oris@oris:~/slim-api$
```

**Questions:**

- Generally, How would I pass an array with curl to this route instead of flat key1=value1, key2=value2 ?
- Why is this change in the test output when the only thing which is changed is the request method?

Oddly, when I dig in a little into Slim code, on `/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Http/Request.php` I see that the `put` function is just an alias for `post`:

```
    /**
 * Fetch PUT data (alias for \Slim\Http\Request::post)
 * @param  string           $key
 * @param  mixed            $default Default return value when key does not exist
 * @return array|mixed|null
 */
public function put($key = null, $default = null)
{
    return $this->post($key, $default);
}
```

Comment: To the person who found this question worthy of down-voting: Can you comment with the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i remember, slim needs to configure the header to accept `'PUT'` method first
OR
you need to add params of `'_METHOD=PUT'` along with the data array, and you send the request as `'POST'`.
the passed params might look like this : `array("_METHOD"=>"PUT","data"=>array("myKey"=>"myValue"))`